# why webhook and API messages are getting called twice using pusher

Tags: javascript, java, chat, webhooks, pusher

> I have created chat application using pusher [java for back-end and
>   iPhone for front-end]
>         From front-end i am calling the client event only once, however it the web-hook supposed to be hit only once on that, but it is
>   getting hit twice and so the API messages which i am triggering on
>   that particular web-hook called twice.

Due to this issue there is problem while syncing the messages.

> client event

```
{
  "at": "1453727819646",
  "ui": "6239487a87904e0ea9b4ebcd1e44f5e5",
  "gi": "5BF88B3CC3E94004A475DB06F1231E87",
  "mt": "3000"
}
```

> The webhook getting hit more than once

```
{
  "time_ms": 1453729661217,
  "events": [
    {
      "name": "client_event",
      "channel": "presence-3ER88B3CC3E94004A475DB06F5631E87",
      "event": "client-event",
      "data": "{\"at\":\"1453727819646\",\"ui\":\"6239487a87904e0ea9b4ebcd1e44f5e5\",\"gi\":\"5BF88B3CC3E94004A475DB06F1231E87\",\"mt\":\"3000\"}",
      "socket_id": "158412.2865564",
      "user_id": "6239487a87904e0ea9b4ebcd1e4ef5e5"
    }
  ]
}
```

On The Pusher Debug Console -the event shown twice there
And On Console of of javascript client file it shows nothing

[image]

calling using following function

```
 $('#chat_widget_form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var chat_widget_input = $('#chat_widget_input'),
            chat_widget_button = $('#chat_widget_button'),
            chat_widget_loader = $('#chat_widget_loader'),

            message = chat_widget_input.val(); //get the value from the text input
            chat_widget_input.val("");

         var messageObj = JSON.parse(message);
console.log("messageObj---->"+messageObj);
    presenceChannel.trigger("client-chat_message", messageObj);


            newMessageCallback(messageObj)
            return false;
        });
```

> I am unable to find out the cause, can anybody tell me where i am
>   going wrong?

Comment: Hi @Kamini, I work at Pusher and so should be able to help out :)

Can you post a gist or copy and paste the code that you've got on the client side where you're triggering your client event?

Comment: @hamchapman updated the question

Comment: That all looks fine in principal. What happens if just for a test you remove the link between submitting the form and the Pusher message being sent and instead just create a new Pusher object on page load, immediately subscribe to the presence channel, bind on subscription succeeded, and then trigger a message? Does that still send two messages? 

My gut instinct is that there's a small bug in your JS code that is leading to duplicates.

Comment: @hamchapman ok i will just check and update you thanks

Comment: @hamchapman hey thanks , identified that with 2 different client event webhook urls(with different IP addresses) it will not work. i have disabled the another one.

Comment: @BhartiRawat I sent you an email.